# EF-Core LINQ JOIN with include()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

**Question**: Is the above possible in EF-Core 1.1? I'm trying the following but `VS2015` complaining on line `Select new TestViewModel{...}` with the error: `name Select does not exist in the current context`. If the above is not possible what's a workaround while sill using `include(...)`? **Note**: `Customers` is joined to `Addresses` and `Orders` table

```
var qry = from c in _context.Customers.Include(t => t.Addresses).Where(c => c.Region== "NW").OrderBy(c => c.Name)
 join ord in _context.Orders  on c.CustomerID equals ord.CustomerID
Select new TestViewModel
{
   CustName = c.Name,
   CustRegion  = c.Region,
   OrderType = ord.Type,
   ....
};
```

Comment: Select should be lower-cased ("select")

Comment: @Evk Thanks. It was my bad. Instead of paying attention to my spelling I started focusing on a possible issue of using `Include(...)` inside `join`. If the rest went ok, I'll let you know. And then you may want to change your comment to a response - and I'll mark that as an `Answer`.

Comment: @Evk The rest also worked. Thanks again. For the benefit of other readers, you may want to convert you comment to a response and I'll make it as an `Answer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` is a keyword, and keywords are case-sensitive. Just like you cannot declare class `Public Static` - you cannot use `Select`.